# API for bigquery.tabledata.insertAll method

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-apis-explorer

Below is my code for writing into a BigQuery table:

```sql
from google.cloud import bigquery

response = bigquery.tabledata.insertAll(projectId=PROJECT_ID,datasetId=DATASET_ID,
            tableId=TABLE_ID,
            body=data).execute()
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
no module tabledata in google.cloud.bigquery
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Which API should I use here?

Comment: which language ? on nodejs ?

Comment: Looks like you are using Python, Check this link which might help you https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/6574 (Check you python version as well)

Comment: @Anwar, please upvote/accept the answer to let community know about usefulness https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Answer (score 0):

Please, check the [Streaming data into BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#bigquery_table_insert_rows-python) documentation. When using python you need to use following function:

```
insert_rows(table, rows, selected_fields=None, **kwargs)
```

which insert rows into a table via the streaming API. For more information refer to following [BigQuery Python API](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html?highlight=client%20insert_rows) reference documentation.

You can check Python streaming insert example:

```
# TODO(developer): Import the client library.
# from google.cloud import bigquery

# TODO(developer): Construct a BigQuery client object.
# client = bigquery.Client()

# TODO(developer): Set table_id to the ID of the model to fetch.
# table_id = "your-project.your_dataset.your_table"

table = client.get_table(table_id)  # Make an API request.
rows_to_insert = [(u"Phred Phlyntstone", 32), (u"Wylma Phlyntstone", 29)]

errors = client.insert_rows(table, rows_to_insert)  # Make an API request.
if errors == []:
    print("New rows have been added.")
```

You can also use API, calling [tabledata.insertAll](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/insertAll?hl=pl) method to see the request and response of API. You need to specify `projectId`, `datasetId`, `tableId`. You can see JavaScript code snippet that is used to perform request:

```
function execute() {
  return gapi.client.bigquery.tabledata.insertAll({
    "projectId": "<your_projectId>",
    "datasetId": "<your_datasetId>",
    "tableId": "<your_tableId>",
    "resource": {}
  })
      .then(function(response) {
              // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
              console.log("Response", response);
            },
            function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
}
```

Let me know about the results.